# correctly grouping documents in aggregate pipeline in order to find setintersection

Tags: mongodb

say I have these two documents:

```
{  
   "_id":"sampleA",
   "value":{  
      "data":[  
         {  
            "thing":"A"
         },
         {  
            "thing":"B"
         },
         {  
            "thing":"C"
         },
         {  
            "thing":"D"
         },
         {  
            "thing":"E"
         }
      ]
   }
}

 {  
   "_id":"sampleB",
   "value":{  
      "data":[  
         {  
            "thing":"C"
         },
         {  
            "thing":"D"
         },
         {  
            "thing":"E"
         },
         {  
            "thing":"F"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and I want to group them into one document, retaining the label of "sampleA" or "sampleB" such as

```
{
  "_id": null,
  "sampleA": [
    {
      "thing": "A"
    },
    {
      "thing": "B"
    },
    {
      "thing": "C"
    },
    {
      "thing": "D"
    },
    {
      "thing": "E"
    }
  ],
  "sampleB": [
    {
      "thing": "C"
    },
    {
      "thing": "D"
    },
    {
      "thing": "E"
    },
    {
      "thing": "F"
    }
  ]
}
```

So that way I can use the set intersection operator. How do I go about doing this? I tried:

```
db.testz.aggregate(
      [{
        $match: {
          _id: {
            $in: ["sampleA", "sampleB"]
          }
        }
      }, {
        '$group': {
          _id: null,
          a: {
            $push: "$value"
          }
        }
      }]
    );
```

which gives me

```
{
  "_id": null,
  "a": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "thing": "A"
        },
        {
          "thing": "B"
        },
        {
          "thing": "C"
        },
        {
          "thing": "D"
        },
        {
          "thing": "E"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "thing": "C"
        },
        {
          "thing": "D"
        },
        {
          "thing": "E"
        },
        {
          "thing": "F"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Presumably I could then use the set intersection operator if I could index the items in a?

```
    db.testz.aggregate(
      [{
        $match: {
          _id: {
            $in: ["sampleA", "sampleB"]
          }
        }
      }, {
        '$group': {
          _id: null,
          a: {
            $push: "$value"
          }
        }
      }, {
        '$project': {
          int: {
            $setIntersection: ["$a.0", "$a.1"]
          }
        }
      }]
    );
```

^^ obviously this last step here doesn't work, but I am trying to illustrate the point.

Comment: Can you explain what the overall purpose of this operation is? Which sets are you trying to intersect? Just the two arrays in the two documents? Arrays in certain pairs of documents in a whole collection? If the former, why not just do this tiny operation in client code? If the latter, we need more explanation of how you're pairing the documents and what the set intersection operation is and is for.

Comment: The former... Just trying to find the intersection of the two data arrays.

Comment: The operation isn't always tiny, at some point the data arrays will contain thousands of things. Also, I will need to find the intersection of more than two "data" arrays (but with the same format).

Comment: So you want the intersection of ALL of the arrays in the collection, one big intersection? It's still not clear precisely what you want.

Comment: From the first document type I listed at the very beginning of my post, assume I have up to n of those documents, and they all contain data with lengths potentially in the thousands. I need to figure out how to group several of those data arrays into a single document so that I can use the set intersection operator on them.

Comment: For now, it doesn't necessarily have to be all the arrays in the collection... Just how I would, given my example, find the intersection of those two data arrays using the set intersection operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this presently (MongoDB 2.6) is to unwind the arrays and then recollect in a set:

```
> db.testz.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "_id" : { "$in" : ["sampleA", "sampleB"] } } },
    { "$unwind" : "$value.data" },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : 0, "intersection" : { "$addToSet" : "$value.data" } } }
])
```

It's not an efficient way to do it, but it gets the job done. I was probing you for more specific info to see if there was some way to avoid this answer :(